# Registry Monitoring and Redirection Help (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, redirect, registry

I'm learning in VB.NET. This is my first language.

I'm trying to build a launcher for an application with uncertain registry write location. I'm working on makeing the application portable. (app is based on low .NET framework for compatibility)

I looked for different methods like forcing registry virtualization or use registry virtualization through an api. (Thinking I can offload the writes if they're consolidated.)

I was also thinking that I could monitor the registry for any writes by a certain PID. I've also looked for an application that did this. Redirected any writes like sandboxie does. But with no luck.

So if I need to add more details tell me and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You might check out a product like VMWare ThinApp or other Application virtualization tools, which will do this automatically for you with no need to write any code.

Maybe its just me, but this sounds like a very complicated thing you are trying to do in your first program.